# Tableau Server Client download image view filter with parameter value

Tags: python, server, parameters, client, tableau-api

I am currently trying to add a view filter on Tableau Server Client through Python to change dashboard parameter values in the view.

For example I want to add a view filter to [this dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mX2r.png), for the parameter Base salary to be $600,000.

I have tried this:

```
image_req_option.vf('Base salary', '600000')
```

But it does not work... Any insight would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, hope this helps.

```
            image_req_option = TSC.PDFRequestOptions(page_type=TSC.PDFRequestOptions.PageType.A4,
                                                   orientation=TSC.PDFRequestOptions.Orientation.Landscape,maxage=1)

            # (optional) set a view filter
            image_req_option.vf('Base salary', '600000')

            server.views.populate_pdf(view, image_req_option)
```